# Some Audio Unit code (incl. auval) does not work in iTerm

Tags: macos, command-line, core-audio, audiounit, iterm2

[I've answered my own question below, and for people searching for this issue in the future, I've replaced the question with a summary of the issue.]

In iTerm v3.2.8-9, "auval -a" does not find any 3rd-party plugins.

It has the same issue with utilities, scripts, etc. that have this kind of code:

- AVAudioUnitManager.shared.manager().components(matching: componentDescription)
- AVAudioUnitManager.shared.manager().components(passingTest: { comp, stop in
- AudioComponentFindNext(comp, &componentDescription)

Apple's Terminal does not have this issue.

Comment: Does System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy show any categories that are not enabled for Terminal?

Comment: I found iTerm in Contacts and Calendars, enabled.  I found it disabled in Accessibility and enabled it, restarted iTerm and ran the script -- no dice.  I also added iTerm (with the Plus icon) to Full Disk Access and restarted iTerm.  Didn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the issue down to a new function that moves "the process from the Aqua 'per-session' namespace to the same user 'per-user' namespace." <- comment in iTerm2 source

iTerm2 Maintainer responded to issue:  "For now, turn off Prefs > Advanced > Allow sessions to survive logging out and back in. I plan to revert that commit in a future release of 3.3.x. See #7947"

For more info:

https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/7946